# event control in assignment in verilog syntax

Tags: verilog

I am currently learning verilog and i got some question while studying.

```
always @(posedge clock)
begin
  reg1 <= #25 in_1;
  reg2 <= @(negedge clock) in_2 ^ in_3;
  reg3 <= in_1;
end
```

From my understanding if code is written like above, the sequence of reg2 is

1. calculate in_2^in_3 at posedge of clock
2. save in_2^in_3 value to reg2 at negedge of clock.

is this right??

To verify my thought, I've tested my code in modelsim 6.6d & vivado 2019.1 and their result was different. I used the same code, but why do I get different waveform?

(test.v)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test(
  input wire clock,
  input wire [2:0] in_1, in_2, in_3,
  
  output reg [2:0] reg1, reg2, reg3
);

always @(posedge clock)
begin
  reg1 <= #25 in_1;
  reg2 <= @(negedge clock) in_2 ^ in_3;
  reg3 <= in_1;
end

endmodule
```

(tb_test.v)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps 

module tb_test();
  
reg clock = 1'b0;
reg [2:0] in_1 = 3'b001;
reg [2:0] in_2 = 3'b010;
reg [2:0] in_3 = 3'b100;

wire [2:0] reg1;
wire [2:0] reg2;
wire [2:0] reg3;

always #5 clock = ~clock;

test uut(
    .clock  (clock),
    .in_1 (in_1),
    .in_2 (in_2),
    .in_3 (in_3),
    .reg1 (reg1), 
    .reg2 (reg2), 
    .reg3 (reg3)
);

endmodule
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understood it correctly. More details follow:

At posedge of clk verilog will create 3 actions in the 'NBA' scheduling region:

```
1. reg1 = #25 in_1;
2. reg2 = @(negedge clock) in_2 ^ in_3;
3. reg3 = in_1;
```

All will run in parallel.

1. value of the in_1 will be captured immediately at posedge clk. However, this value will only be assigned to reg1 in 25ns. Till that time, the old value of reg1 will stay.
2. similar story to reg2. It will capture the result of in_2^in_3 at posedge clk, then it will assign it to reg2 at negedge of clk.
3. will assign the value immediately in the nba region.

Just note that such code is not synthesizable and can be used in test bench only.

Comment: what about the testbench waveform? are they just compiler issue?

Comment: no idea. looks like waveform 2 is wrong. I have never seen use of your #2 example anywhere, including in standard. It can be prone to implementation details. So, as toolic suggested, do not ever use it.

Comment: @Serge the #2 example is in the standard [IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) section 9.4.5 _Intra-assignment timing controls_ . There are even more complex examples in the LRM. These event based delays cannot be used for synthesizable code, but are useful for certain BFM requirements.

Comment: @Greg Thanks Greg, I missed it before. There is a nice table.